# Manipulating the contents of the `spy in` node with `tikz` `spy` library

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [spy using outlines={circle, magnification=7, size=3cm, connect spies}]

  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \path (2,2) node[fill, rectangle, inner sep=2pt, minimum height=1cm] (n) {};

  \draw[dotted] (n.south west) -- (n.south west |- 0,0);
  \draw[dotted] (n.south east) -- (n.south east |- 0,0);

  \spy on ($(n.south east |- 0,0)!0.5!(n.south west |- 0,0)$) 
    in node at (3,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: mew]

There are two problems:

1. The dotted lines become a couple of dots. Can I change the style of the line inside the `spy in` node (leaving the original one unchanged) so that the frequency of the dot symbols is higher and the dotted line appears as such in the `spy in` node as well?
2. Can I reference nodes or coordinates inside the `spy in` nodes in some way? That's because I'd need to draw a distance measurment mark between the zoomed versions of the two dotted lines.

Comment: I feel that if you want to make such drastic changes, you may not want to use spy at all, but just draw whatever you like in a circle node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel that if you want to make such drastic changes, you may not want to use spy at all, but just draw whatever you like in a circle node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [spy using outlines={circle, magnification=7, size=3cm, connect spies}]

  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \path (2,2) node[fill, rectangle, inner sep=2pt, minimum height=1cm] (n) {};

  \draw[dotted] (n.south west) -- (n.south west |- 0,0);
  \draw[dotted] (n.south east) -- (n.south east |- 0,0);

  \draw  let \p1=($(n.south east)-(n.south west)$)
   in   ($(n.south east |- 0,0)!0.5!(n.south west |- 0,0)$)
   node[circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3cm/7](small){}
    (3,-2)
   node[circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3cm,
   path picture={
   \draw[line width=7*0.8pt] 
   (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
   \draw[thick,dotted] (-7*\x1/2,0) --  (-7*\x1/2,3) 
    (7*\x1/2,0) --  (7*\x1/2,3); 
   \draw[|<->|] (-7*\x1/2,0.8) -- (7*\x1/2,0.8)
    node[midway,fill=white,minimum size=0pt,rectangle]{$\Delta x$};  }]
   (big){} (small) -- (big);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may use this to annotate the `spy` node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [spy using outlines={circle, magnification=7, size=3cm, connect spies}]

  \draw[->, very thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
  \path (2,2) node[fill, rectangle, inner sep=2pt, minimum height=1cm] (n) {};

  \draw[densely dotted] (n.south west) -- (n.south west |- 0,0);
  \draw[densely dotted] (n.south east) -- (n.south east |- 0,0);

  \spy on ($(n.south east |- 0,0)!0.5!(n.south west |- 0,0)$) 
    in node at (3,-2);
  \draw  let \p1=($(n.south east)-(n.south west)$),\n1={7*\x1/2-7*0.2pt}
   in  (3,-2)
   node[circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3cm,
   path picture={
   \draw[|<->|] (-\n1,0.8) -- (\n1,0.8)
    node[midway,fill=white,minimum size=0pt,rectangle]{$\Delta x$};  }]
   (big){}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a working solution for this MWE, but this was a shrinked down version of something more complex, where it is hard, if at all possible, to recreate the contents of the spy node by hand.

Comment: @gigabytes `spy` copies the content of a box. So you cannot easily manipulate its contents. You can overlay stuff in the way described here.

Comment: I see. I suppose the library could be extended to provide at least access to the copies of the nodes. For instance, the magnified copy of a node (n) may be called (spy-n), so that it could be accessed easily. I don't know whether this addition to the library would be easy to obtain. Maybe I should file a feature request on GitHub or wherever the project is hosted.

Comment: @gigabytes I don't think it will be easy to reconstruct the contents in such a way that it becomes a set of nodes. What you can do is to use the code to annotate a spy node, I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that, but I'm having difficulties understanding what is going on. Can you elaborate a bit on how it works?

Comment: @gigabytes If I know what you do not understand I can try to explain it.

Comment: Nevermind. The positions are placed "manually", right? I thought you were somehow computing them somehow.

Comment: @gigabytes They are computed from the other data. It might look "manual" because I subtract half of the scaled line width.

Comment: Yes, clear. Thank you :)